# Directx 11: Print error messages on output debug window of MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have a question about how to print error messages on the MS visual 2010. I am writing an application using DirectX 11 and CUDA. There is an error thrown from the CUDA function call to cudaGraphicsMapResources( nbResources, ppResources, stream). I got a function to print the error message but nothing got printed on the output debug window. The following is the the function to print the error message:

```
inline void __getLastCudaError( const char *errorMessage, const char *file, const int line )
{
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
    if( cudaSuccess != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(%i) : getLastCudaError() CUDA error : %s : (%d) %s.\n",
                file, line, errorMessage, (int)err, cudaGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

How to make this function working properly in DirectX 11? This function should print an error statement on the output window.

Comment: It doesn't, use OutputDebugString() instead.

Comment: Can you please explain why it doesn't?

Comment: As far as I know, stderr is in no way related to the output Window of VS.